# Search and update userform

Tags: excel, forms, vba, search

I have this code that I found online for a VBA search userform.

I would like to make some modification so the result shown include data from other columns of the found cell line instead of giving only the Address.

I would eventually like to be able to change the value in those cells from the userform itself. So I can search a specific line and update the table.

Here's the code:

```
    Private Sub TextBox_Find_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
'Calls the FindAllMatches routine as user types text in the textbox

    Call FindAllMatches

End Sub

Private Sub Label_ClearFind_Click()
'Clears the find text box and sets focus

    Me.TextBox_Find.Text = ""
    Me.TextBox_Find.SetFocus

End Sub

Sub FindAllMatches()
'Find all matches on activesheet
'Called by: TextBox_Find_KeyUp event

Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim FindWhat As Variant
Dim FoundCells As Range
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim arrResults() As Variant
Dim lFound As Long
Dim lSearchCol As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long

    If Len(f_FindAll.TextBox_Find.Value) > 1 Then 'Do search if text in find box is longer than 1 character.

        Set SearchRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells

        FindWhat = f_FindAll.TextBox_Find.Value
        'Calls the FindAll function
        Set FoundCells = FindAll(SearchRange:=SearchRange, _
                                FindWhat:=FindWhat, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                MatchCase:=False, _
                                BeginsWith:=vbNullString, _
                                EndsWith:=vbNullString, _
                                BeginEndCompare:=vbTextCompare)
        If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
            ReDim arrResults(1 To 1, 1 To 2)
            arrResults(1, 1) = "No Results"
        Else
            'Add results of FindAll to an array
            ReDim arrResults(1 To FoundCells.Count, 1 To 2)
            lFound = 1
            For Each FoundCell In FoundCells
                arrResults(lFound, 1) = FoundCell.Value
                arrResults(lFound, 2) = FoundCell.Address
                lFound = lFound + 1
            Next FoundCell
        End If

        'Populate the listbox with the array
        Me.ListBox_Results.List = arrResults

    Else
        Me.ListBox_Results.Clear
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox_Results_Click()
'Go to selection on sheet when result is clicked

Dim strAddress As String
Dim l As Long

    For l = 0 To ListBox_Results.ListCount
        If ListBox_Results.Selected(l) = True Then
            strAddress = ListBox_Results.List(l, 1)
            ActiveSheet.Range(strAddress).Select
            GoTo EndLoop
        End If
    Next l

EndLoop:

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton_Close_Click()
'Close the userform

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: You can access other cells in the same row using (eg) `FoundCell.EntireRow.Cells(4).Value` (Column D value)  Try making the changes you want, then post back if you run into problems.

Comment: Ok so using FoundCell.EntireRow.Cells(4).Value works fine but I can't get more than 2 columns of data showing up in the form. Any idea what can I change in this code to have more than 2 information per line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example for four columns of data, edit your form's listbox to set `ColumnCount` to 4 and edit your code as below:

```
    '....
    If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
        ReDim arrResults(1 To 1, 1 To 4)  '<<<edit
        arrResults(1, 1) = "No Results"
    Else
        'Add results of FindAll to an array
        ReDim arrResults(1 To FoundCells.Count, 1 To 4) '<<<edit
        lFound = 1
        For Each FoundCell In FoundCells
            arrResults(lFound, 1) = FoundCell.Value
            arrResults(lFound, 2) = FoundCell.Address
            'EDIT: adding two new columns
            arrResults(lFound, 3) = FoundCell.EntireRow.Cells(4).Value
            arrResults(lFound, 4) = FoundCell.EntireRow.Cells(5).Value

            lFound = lFound + 1
        Next FoundCell
    End If

    'Populate the listbox with the array
    Me.ListBox_Results.List = arrResults
    '....
```